# Is it better to use a pre compiled jasper file or compile the jrxml template during runtime?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have following 2 options to generate a PDF using jasper.

Using Pre-Compiled Jrxml (.jasper) file as given in sample code below

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDS = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List<JavaObject>);
File jasperFile = new File("JasperTemplate.jasper");
JasperReport jr = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperFile);
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("REPORT_TITLE", "Test Report");
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, beanCollectionDS);
```

Using Jasper Template (.jrxml) file which gets compiled at runtime as given in sample code below

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDS = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List<JavaObject>);
String template = "JasperTemplate.jrxml";
InputStream reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(template);
JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("REPORT_TITLE", "Test Report");
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, beanCollectionDS);
```

Which approach is better and why.

Comment: See [When should I compile my report templates and how?](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/when-should-i-compile-my-report-templates-and-how)

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the answer provided by @Andreas.

---

**The exact moment when report compilation needs to occur depends on whether report design templates change during the application's execution.**

If report designs (JRXMLs) do not change at runtime, that is the application only provides dynamic data and parameter values to predefined report templates, report designs can be considered application source code and it is recommended to compile them during the application build process and to include the compile reports (*.jasper files) in the binary/deployed application.

In more complex scenarios if the report templates need to be generated, changed or deployed at runtime, they have to be compiled at runtime. In such cases it is recommended to use the JDK-based report compiler because:

- It doesn't need to use (temporary) files, like the JDK-based report
  compilers.
- It uses the context classloader to resolve classes, while JDK-based
  report compiler work with a filesystem classpath that needs to be set
  up by the user.

Comment: I am confused by your recommendation. You say "it is recommended to use the JDK-compiler..." but than you bring up to points against it?